# Does WordPress Cron API Run in the Background?

Tags: php, cron, wordpress

I'm reading the code of `cron.php` in wp-includes and `spawn_cron()` seems to be the one which actually executes registered tasks.

The last two lines of the function:

```
$cron_url = site_url( 'wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=' . $doing_wp_cron );

wp_remote_post( $cron_url, array( 'timeout' => 0.01, 'blocking' => false, 'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ) ) );
```

It simply opens wp-cron.php passing a task an as a query argument.

The description of the API at the top of cron.php:

```
* Schedules a hook which will be executed once by the WordPress actions core at 
* a time which you specify. The action will fire off when someone visits your
* WordPress site, if the schedule time has passed.`
```

My question is that let's say the visitor opens one of the pages of the site and then the registered task is fired by the cron API. And if the task is heavy and takes several minutes to complete, does the visitor gets a page that is not completely loaded until the task finishes?

[Edit]
To clarify what I'm asking, the question is, does the WP Cron API run tasks after the page loading completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cron_url = site_url( 'wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=' . $doing_wp_cron );
wp_remote_post( $cron_url, array( 'timeout' => 0.01, 'blocking' => false, 'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ) ) );
```

With the below sample plugin, I confirmed that the above code (I quoted in the question as well) is the one actually calls scheduled tasks. It sets 0.0.1 timeout and accesses to wp-cron.php. This means if there are 100 tasks it takes 1 seconds to load all tasks. So it has a slight impact on the page loading speed. But it seems to be something not to worry about too much.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Sample Cron Task */ 

    // I used `heavy` because this code was initially written to test how it affects the server response if a heavy task is registered as a cron job. So forget about the naming.
add_action('admin_menu', 'sample_cron_heavy_task');
function sample_cron_heavy_task() {
    add_options_page(
        'Sample Cron Heavy Task', 
        'Sample Cron Heavy Task', 
        'manage_options',
        'sample_cron_heavy_task', 
        'sample_cron_heavy_task_admin');
}
function sample_cron_heavy_task_admin() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'my_action_name');
        $cron_url = site_url( 'wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=' . $doing_wp_cron );
        // executes the registered task immediately 
        wp_remote_post( $cron_url, array( 'timeout' => 0.01, 'blocking' => false, 'sslverify' => apply_filters( 'https_local_ssl_verify', true ) ) );
        echo get_option('sample_cron_heavy_task');
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('my_action_name', 'myevent'); 
function myevent() {
    $msg = date('Y m d h:i:s A') . ': the cron task is called.<br />';
    update_option('sample_cron_heavy_task', $msg);
}
```

Comment: does the visitor gets a page that is not completely loaded until the task finishes?

Answer (score -1):

The cron job should not effect your viewer at all.  If it does find a new hosting company.

Comment: As long as your functions are setup up properly they should still recieve the data needed to create the page.  There should never be a pause in retrieval from the database.

Comment: I'm still having hard time getting what you say. `if it does find a new hosting company`, `to create the page`, and `retrieval from the database` do not sound relevant to the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was just saying that in no way should it effect the viewer of your website.

Comment: My concern is that tasks are triggered by opening a hidden page after someone accesses one of the pages; then how do I know that the page gets completely loaded.

Comment: The first thing wordpress does when loading the page is query the database.  After that it populates the page with a single query.  I suppose that in some cases a plugin may recall the database, however in that case it would just pull the new content. You should never have a point where content is not available.

Comment: I'm not fully able to absorb what you say. I'm not sure how the question relates to database queries. Let me rephrase the question. Does the WP Cron API run tasks after the page loading completes?

Comment: A cron script is ment to be a scheduled task that you have to set server side. These tasks should only run when you tell them to and I would not run a cron script every time someone views a page. If you were to run one on page load it would run before loading the content as it would be a server side script.

Comment: I'm talking about WP Cron, which works differently than regular linux/unix cron jobs. That's why I quoted the last two lines of the API in the initial post.

Comment: It will run the job before the page loads as it is run in php. As long as your functions are setup up properly they should still recieve the data needed to create the page within a reasonable time.

Comment: How can I confirm that the task will be executed before the visitor loads the page?

Comment: Add something an echo 'Test' to the cron to see if it displays at the top of the script or bottom.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't display anything. Probably it's because it runs in the background. But I'd like to know if it's affecting the page loading speed.